# query django date

Tags: django, django-views

In ,models i have

```
         class pick:
          t1 =models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

In views.

The date variable is in the format `s="2010-01-01"`

```
         How o query the for the date now

          pick.objects.filter(t1=date(s))
```

Comment: Please format your questions properly.

Answer (score 1):

datetime.date() expected arguments are `datetime.date(year, month, day)`, so creating a date object with `s` won't work. But you can use the date string directly in filter like

```
picks_at_date = pick.objects.filter(t1=s)
```

or when you try to find anything before or after that date

```
picks_before_date = pick.objects.filter(t1__lt=s)
```

or

```
picks_after_date = pick.objects.filter(t1__gt=s).
```

Django's "Making queries" Docs at [Retrieving specific objects with filters](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) has some good examples on making queries with date fields as well.